# how to achieve this lighting?

Tags: materials, lighting

I have this anime head that I am working on and I would like to achieve this lighting:
[image]

the girl here looks like she has actual flesh, but mine looks plastic and boring.

here is mine. What can I do to improve this? how can I make her skin look like skin like the other artist? and how can I get that lighting. file:https://blend-exchange.com/b/g5MWZRe1
[image]

Comment: Your blend upload has missing image files, they weren't packed in before you uploaded.  (Not sure how much I can do anyway, we're about to experience a "weather impact event" here, but for whoever gives it a shot . . . )

Comment: oh crap, i have no idea how to pack them, how do I do that?

Comment: also, sorry to hear you're in a bad situation, I hope you are staying safe!

Comment: Yeah, we should be fine -- we have a woodstove if we loose power, and ice to chock the fridge/freezer won't be a problem -- here's how to pack your blend:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139054/how-to-pack-images-into-blend-file

Comment: good! dang i tried it and it made the file too big to upload to sharing sites, anything I can do?

Comment: I'd normally recommend truncating the file to just the problem, but that won't work here.  Overall I think you're close to what you want.  Are you using some Subsurface on the skin material of your model?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253413/how-to-make-material-look-like-soft-plastic-toy/253419#253419  And I've found the twitter you got your goal image from, they did that in Blender, have you tried asking them about their lighting?  I'll try to work up an example if nobody else answers, it might be a couple days.

Comment: she has quite a bit of sub surf on her, I will try to add more. i did try asking on their art station. thank you!

Comment: No, don't -- too much Subsurface can be worse than too little.  Fix the lighting like Timmethy suggests, then see what (if anything) more the skin needs.

Comment: i adjusted the lighting to be more similar but it is lacking still. the skin is too smooth. i don't know what the issue is. its not like the reference has any texture or bumps yet it looks like flesh. here is what I got so far: https://imgur.com/a/IlvpyxW

Comment: This look is better achieved in eevee, is there a special reason you're using cycles?

Comment: eevee just lacks the quality maybe, it changes how good it looks to me. i  tried eevee and in some ways I like it better, in others no. ill try again

Answer (score 3):

As KickAir8p mentioned using subsurface might improve the skin.
Concerning the lighting, your model has a bright light above the head pointing downwards. Your reference seems to be lit from the front (a bit to the left) and only slightly raised. Most likely there's also some additional lighting.

When you want to figure out how an image is lit it helps to convert it to black and white. Then it is easier to see where shadows and highlight are. If you know where the shadows are (below the chin in this case) you can "reverse engineer" the position of the lamp(s).

Edit:

I took a look at your file.
First thing: the heads scale was off. It was almost 1m big, so I scaled it down to a roughly human size and applied the scale .

Second: You have a lot of lamps in the file.

[image]

You can check some tutorials on how photographers set up their lighting when shooting portraits. It's mostly not more then 2-4 light sources.

I quickly set up a material for the skin:

[image]

and reduced the Specular and Roughness values on your hair.
This is how it turns out in Eevee:

[image]

And in Cycles:

[image]

I lit this scene with only three Arealamps:

[image]

Comment: i added more subsurf but it didnt fix the skin issue. for some reason my skin looks too flat while hers seems somehow slightly textured and that is has depth and I cant tell why.

Comment: and im gonna try the black and white thing, great idea